# Expand Width on Custom Community Page

Tags: lightning-community

I have created a custom community page and it is very narrow. Is there anyway I can adjust the width of the page? See attached.

[image]

Comment: What is the template you are using? How does your code look like? Is this a VF page or Lighting Component? Providing these information will help here to reach out to a greater audience and get help. You may like to take a tour of [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yo might want to include the relevant code.

Comment: Napili. Custom lightning page, no code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the form + form elements with Chrome Debugger; F12 or right click the element and 'Inspect'.  Make note of the HTML element classes then target them in the CSS which you can place in the 'Edit Head Markup' found Builder->Settings->Advanced.

ie:

`.slds-form .slds-form-element input {
    width: 100%;
}`

Or depending on how you created this custom page just apply the Lightning Design System styling:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com